# How can I have WebSockets connect to a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: websocket, google-cloud-functions

I have a WebSocket that I'm subscribing to and when an event comes in, I want to trigger a Google Cloud Function. Is this possible?

For example, I'm listening to https://alpaca.markets/docs/api-documentation/api-v2/streaming/

And whenever I get `trade_updates`, I want to run a function on Google cloud Functions

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is you want to happen?  I'm not sure from your description where the connection between the browser and the websocket currently terminates.

Comment: Added more to explain.

Comment: Cloud Function doesn't support Websocket (triggering or data transfer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All trigger types for Cloud Functions are listed here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling

Web Sockets are not directly supported as a trigger type.

The closest I can think of is setting up an architecture like this:

[image: overview of the architecture]

So here you have some code listening to the web socket and then triggering Cloud Functions through Pub/Sub or one of the other supported trigger types.

Comment: So then doesn’t that middle piece of code (that’s long running) take away the whole point of using a FaaS?

Comment: Partially yes. But you should be able to keep this code very lightweight, especially if you do asynchronous events only (so not waiting for a response). That way a single compute instance could handle *a lot* of events. You could also run it on another auto-scaling infrastructure, but it'd still be auto-scaling containers rather than pure FaaS.

Comment: Is this still true in 2024? Other places indicate otherwise, but there is no definite answer