# Publishing WebSocket events to Pub/Sub

Tags: docker, websocket, etl, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I would like to create a streaming pipeline which uses a WebSocket connection to ingest real-time trading events and then publish them to a Pub/Sub topic.

My original idea was to use a cloud function which gets triggered frequently and publishes the payloads into Pub/Sub, at which point a subscriber ingests the data into BigQuery. The problem with this approach is that Google's cloud function service does not support the use of any websocket libraries. [See this StackOverflow post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174191/how-can-i-have-websockets-connect-to-a-google-cloud-function/62175728#comment134672134_62175728).

As an alternative, I am considering to build my pipeline in a container and deploy it either as a Cloud Run instance or on Kubernetes, similar to how it's done in [this repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-bigquery-python/tree/master/pubsub). What I am struggling with is how triggering will work. Assuming that data is constantly flowing, I need to constantly run my pipeline once deployed. This is how my event-listener (main.py) script looks:

```
import websocket
import simplejson as json
import time
import ssl
import os
import json
from google.api_core.exceptions import NotFound
from google.cloud.pubsub import PublisherClient
from google.pubsub_v1.types import Encoding
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.types import (
    LimitExceededBehavior,
    PublisherOptions,
    PublishFlowControl
)


# Configure environment variables

project_id = "project_id"
topic_id = "pubsub_topic_id"



# Initialize publishing client, specify publisher settings and point it to the topic path

publisher_options = pubsub_v1.types.PublisherOptions(enable_message_ordering=False)
client_options = {"api_endpoint": "eu-west4-pubsub.googleapis.com:443"}
publisher_client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(publisher_options=publisher_options, client_options=client_options)
topic_path = publisher_client.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
topic = publisher_client.get_topic(request={"topic": topic_path})
encoding = topic.schema_settings.encoding



# Establish connection to WebSocket stream

ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
ws.connect("wss://crypto.financialmodelingprep.com/")



# Define login, subscribe and unsubscribe events for WebSocket listener

login = {
    'event':'login',
    'data': {
        'apiKey': "api_key",
    }
}
subscribe = {
    'event':'subscribe',
    'data': {
        'ticker': "btcusd",
    }
}
unsubscribe = {
    'event':'unsubscribe',
    'data': {
        'ticker': "btcusd",
    }
}



ws.send(json.dumps(login))          # Send login request
time.sleep(1)                       # Wait for 1 second to prevent timeout
ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe))      # Subscribe listener
time.sleep(10)                      # Stream data for 10 seconds
ws.send(json.dumps(unsubscribe))    # Unsubscribe listener




# -- Function which fixes improper UNIX timestamp -- #

def filterts(dct):
    if len(dct) > 3:
        dct["t"] = round(dct.get("t") / 1000)
    return dct




while True:
    record = filterts(json.loads(ws.recv()))
    try:
        if encoding == Encoding.JSON and (len(record) > 3):                     # Do not accept event notifications (i.e., subscribed, unsubscribed)
            data_str = json.dumps(record)                                       # Prepare the record for publishing
            print(f"Preparing a JSON-encoded message:\n{data_str}")
            data = data_str.encode("utf-8")                                     
        else:
            print(f"No encoding specified in {topic_path}. Abort.")
            exit(0)


        
        future = publisher_client.publish(topic_path, data)                     # Publish JSON payload to topic
        print(f"Published message ID: {future.result()}")

    except NotFound:
        print(f"{topic_id} not found.")
```

As you can see, I can configure how long events are streamed for via the `time.sleep(n)` function. The issue is, I get a timeout after one hour of listening and the script finishes with an error. How can I set up my app so that it automatically re-executes after the 1 hour threshold is reached?

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything further.

Comment: Could you give some more details about the error message you're facing and the environment(eg.. cloud run,cloud function and version ..etc) you are using to run your code?